# Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

I have upgrade my mac OS to 10.10 beta. Now I have installed Xcode 5.0.2 . When I am creating any project in this and try to build or run it .. It's giving me a compilation error that is

```
Assertion failed: (host_bootstrap_port != MACH_PORT_NULL), function _sim_host_bootstrap_init, file /SourceCache/Interposition_Sim/Interposition_Sim-111/libSystem/system/bootstrap.c, line 26.
```

2014-08-26 12:04:34.258 ibtoold[698:44352] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)"
2014-08-26 12:04:34.259 ibtoold[698:44352] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3747/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:313
Details:  IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool() failed: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fd2a53c59a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd2a53c8bb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (702) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 6.}
Function: IBMessageChannelCocoaTouchToolProxy *IBAttachToCocoaTouchToolFailingGracefully(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *__strong, NSError *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code

Please help me to get rid of this crash

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bug of OS X 10.10. [See this for more info](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6385584100605952).

Comment: Thanks. And what about 5.1.1? When I am trying to install it from mac store , it is saying 'too new OS version to install'. If I install it direct from 5.1.1 dmg, will it be installed in my machine?

Comment: @Adi > I didn't find any solve. About installing 5.1.1 from dmg you can try, but I am not sure.

Comment: After all these discussion and references i got into conclusion that only beta version of iOS 6.0 can work for it. and not the 5.0.2 or 5.1.1. ..... Right now i am using Xcode 6 beta3 instead.